# how i can change it using the command line?

Tags: command-line, output

There is a txt file

```
ID1 PROJECT1 USER1 ROLE1 USER2 ROLE2 USER3 ROLE3
ID2 PROJECT2 USER1 ROLE2 USER2 ROLE2 USER3 ROLE3
```

I need  as below

```
ID1 PROJECT1 USER1 ROLE1
ID1 PROJECT1 USER2 ROLE2
ID1 PROJECT1 USER3 ROLE3
ID2 PROJECT2 USER1 ROLE1
ID2 PROJECT2 USER2 ROLE2
ID2 PROJECT2 USER3 ROLE3
```

Comment: Explain further. Does every line of the input have exactly three users, or can it have an arbitrary number? Are there spaces anywhere except between the fields?

Comment: spaces only between the columns, there can be a lot of users, the main thing for me is to get the idea, because nothing comes to my  mind

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is suited to `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=3;i<NF;i=i+2) print $1,$2,$i,$(i+1)}' file.txt
ID1 PROJECT1 USER1 ROLE1
ID1 PROJECT1 USER2 ROLE2
ID1 PROJECT1 USER3 ROLE3
ID2 PROJECT2 USER1 ROLE2
ID2 PROJECT2 USER2 ROLE2
ID2 PROJECT2 USER3 ROLE3
```